# Android Studio Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' with special chars in username

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

i have a strange error with AAPT2 iin Android Studio. I think it has something to do with german special characters in my account name in windows.

If i set my gradle to version 3.0.1 and also set `android.enableAapt2` to `false` everything works fine. But since i researched, setting the option is not a solution to the problem.

Now if i set the gradle version to 3.1.2 and remove `android.enableAapt2` from the properties i get the following error message:

[image]

And this one:

[image]

One way to solve the problem was to create a new account in windows without special chars in the name. It compiled and did run very well. I really tried everything in the web but could not find a solution to the problem.

Maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** of all check your build log botom of the build section you shared whether any error related to your project showing or not. If error showing then fix those. Build and run again and fix all the error comes up. It will eliminate aapt2 issue without changing android gradle plugin.

**Secondly** if there is not any project related error showing in the build log but still its showing aapt2 error then you can fix it by following below steps.

Update your android gradle plugin in your project level build.gradle file like below:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha13'
```

Now update `android.enableAapt2=true`. Then check and build your project.

Comment: This is another issue. There is nothing project related in the logs. As i mentioned i tried it on another account on windows without special chars and it works. And now it also does with the change to 3.2.0-alpha13! Thank you very much!